# How to center search icon in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have problem in 2 things:

- How do I Make the search bar in left on desktop side as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FLIq.png) and how to avoid [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2F4d.png)
  On small devices?
- When the display is small, it shows a button to display the list, but when I click the button, nothing happens

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="App">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</div>
```

What I tried:
1: I tried using css text-align: left and it doesen't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could use some css to add flex-grow and a max-width

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>AA</title>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="App">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="flex-wrap: nowrap;">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" style="flex-grow: 1; max-width: 300px; width: auto; flex-wrap: nowrap;">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" style="flex-grow: 1;">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```